# An example for (∃y)(Fy→(∀x)Fx)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I am very confused how this can be possible. Could someone give me a substitution instance?

If this is not correct, is there anything wrong with this proof ?

```
├ (∃y)(Fy→(∀x)Fx)
[1] 1. (∃x)~Fx                              A
[1] 2. ~Fa                                  1, EE
[3] 3. Fa                                   A   
[1,3] 4. (Fa•~Fa)                           2,3, Conj
[3] 5. ~(∃x)~Fx                             4, RAA
[3] 6. (∀x)Fx                               5, (Ex.7)
7. (Fa→(∀x)Fx)                              6, RCP
8. (∃y) (Fy→(∀x)Fx)                         7, EI
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean with "a substitution instance" ? See [Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)).

Comment: It means an example corresponding to that argument form

Comment: See the so-called [Drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

Comment: (5) should be the negation of the assumption on (3), not  on (1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mauro said, this statement is often referred to as the Drinker Paradox: there is someone such that if that person drinks, then everyone drinks.

The statement is valid, since we know that either everyone drinks (in which case the statement is clearly true), or not everyone drinks, in which case we can point to any non-drinker to make the statement vacuously true.

Your proof is unfortunately incorrect. Note how line 7 is saying that if $a$ has property F then everything has property F ... that cannot be a valid statement: just because one object a has property F should of course not imply that everything has property F. So, something is wrong. But where? That actually depends on how exactly your rules are defined ... but probably either your EE rule works a little different than you make it out to be, or you are not allowed to introduce Fa as a standalone assumption after you have introduced the a on line 2, or (as Dan suggests in the comments) on line 5 you should remove 3 from your asumption base, rather than line 1.

To try and fix your proof, I would follow the strategy as mentioned before: first prove, using the Law of Excluded Middle pattern, that either everything has property F or not, and then do a proof by cases on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set-theoretic version of your statement: In any set theory that disallows the existence of a universal set (i.e. if every set must exclude something), then for any set F and logical proposition P, we have:

> There exists x, (x in F => P)

regardless of whether P is true or not. For more details see my blog posting [The Drinker's Paradox](http://dcproof.com/DrinkersParadox.html).

Moral of the story: Beware of implications with existential quantifiers. Really weird things can happen.

Comment: @David Ooops! Should be existential quantifier. Made correction.